# What is the Go equivalent of C++ initializer lists?

Tags: go, initializer-list

In C++, I might do the following:

```
for (const string& key : {"foo", "bar", "baz"}) {
  DoSomeThingWithKey(key);
}
```

The `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` is a `std:initializer_list`.  Awesomeness.

Is there an equivalent idiomatic pattern for Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a slice:

```
for _, value := range []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"} {
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

or alternatively an array:

```
for _, value := range [...]string{"foo", "bar", "baz"} {
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

Comment: Or array: `range [...]string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}`

Comment: @kostya Thanks for the hint, added it to the answer.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I didn't realize that the [] and [...] had different effects (slice vs array).  I ended up using this technique.  It's rather verbose, especially if the type name is long, but it does work.